# How do I make my phone stop starting in charge only mode when I plug it in?

Tags: settings, usb, usb-debugging, usb-connection-mode

I did something with developer mode and now whenever I plug my phone in it wont let me access the files until I pull down the task bar and tap on "Charging via USB" which brings up a window where i can change it to "Transfer files". But I have to do this every time and it's so annoying that I basically don't transfer files to/from my phone any more.

In settings > system > developer options I disabled USB debugging, but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: In Settings -> Developer options-> Select USB Configuration, try to selecting MTP (Media Transfer Protocol).

Comment: I re-enabled the "developer options" switch at the top so I could edit it, but the "Select usb configuration" option was already set to MTP. It still seems to default to charging only though.

Comment: Did you recently update the device? Which Android are you running?

Comment: @stackers that developer options setting works only in screen unlocked. This is the default behavior since Android-6, as a security measure: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/fcf10f7c12cb3107bdfedce6f76a8c866d154f3c. There are third party root solutions though which may set MTP as default.

Comment: i have android version 8. i think i tried to set up something for development, but don't need it anymore

Answer (score 1):

At least on my device, it is a default behavior and cannot be altered. It was brought in with Android 8 and is same on 9 and 10.
The default USB connection mode is always charging. You need to manually enable the file transfer mode when needed.

Comment: Although I can find no technical reference for this information, this is my experience as well. The general explanation in other groups is it's a security issue in case you connect to an unknown device (say to charge it) and it attempts to load malicious software, possible of MTP or PTP is the default connection type.

Comment: @acejavelin [technical reference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/fcf10f7c12cb3107bdfedce6f76a8c866d154f3c). It makes sense even if we don't consider the malicious software thing. We are not always with phone when it's locked (feel more secure). We leave it for a few minutes and one could simply access our data by connecting it to a PC. That's like ridiculing the locked screen.